# jquery-ui menu doesn't work as it expected

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I want to make a menu with jquery-ui menu widget, but it not work as it has to.

The code is a basic sample:

```
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $("#menu").menu();
            });
        </script>
        <style>
            .ui-menu
            {
                width: 150px;
            }
        </style>

        <ul id="menu">
            <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item 3</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Item 3-1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Item 3-2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Item 3-3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Item 3-4</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Item 3-5</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Item 4</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item 5</a></li>
        </ul>
```

It always appears like this (The inner menu is always visible):

[image]

Any idea?

Comment: [Works fine here](http://jsfiddle.net/VPmDG/). Are you overriding styles or anything like that? Inspect the menu with whichever dev toolset you are using

Comment: Can you upload this code on jsFiddle?
It's looks fine so I suggest you have another scripts on your page which override or maybe trigger click event on `a` tags.

Comment: check out the answer i've given @jannagy02

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must have probably missed one of the following library or stylesheet otherwise i dont see any error in the code.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
```

Here is a working fiddle for you: http://jsfiddle.net/NrfW8/

Comment: The problem is with my versions. I use ASP.NET MVC4 Template. It has the jquery-1.7.1 and jquery-ui-1.8.20

Answer (score 0):

use this jQuery script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
                $("#menu").menu();
                $("#inner").hide();
                $("#i3").click(function() {
                $("#inner").toggle(); });

            });
```

after changing the html code to :

```
<li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
            <li id="i3"><a href="#">Item 3</a>
                <ul id="inner">
                    <li><a href="#">Item 3-1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Item 3-2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Item 3-3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Item 3-4</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Item 3-5</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Item 4</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item 5</a></li>
        </ul>
```

checkout the jsfiddle i've made for you : http://jsfiddle.net/8ryps/